# Form validation in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a form in oracle apex to make production records, I have the date, time, area and line fields.

How can I do so that the user does not enter repeated data on the same day?
For example, if the 7/7/20 already registered at 7 am, how to validate so that someone else does not enter a registration from 7/7/20 at 7 am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the database take care about it. How? Create **unique index** on those columns, e.g.

```
create unique index ui1_prod on production (cdate, ctime);
```